# Tkinter - Changing all Button text alphabets to uppercase on a Button click

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making an on-screen keyboard using Tkinter and I want to implement a 'Shift' button to capitalize letters on click just like on a real keyboard.
I wish to know how do I implement this functionality?

Before clicking the Shift button my list should look like

```
buttons = [
    '!', 'q', 'w', 'e', 'r', 't', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o', 'p', '←', '7', '8', '9', '-',
    'Tab', 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', '[', ']', '4', '5', '6', '+',
    'Shift', 'z', 'x', 'c', 'v', 'b', 'n', 'm', ',', '.', '/', '?', '*', '1', '2', '3',
    ' Space ' 
]
```

and after clicking the shift button I want my button list to look like

```
shift_buttons = [
    '!', 'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P', '←', '7', '8', '9', '-',
    'Tab', 'A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', '[', ']', '4', '5', '6', '+',
    'Shift', 'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M', ',', '.', '/', '?', '*', '1', '2', '3',
    ' Space ' 
]
```

In short, how can I make the Button text change from first list to second list just by clicking a Button widget ?

Comment: Where is the button code, please include that too

Comment: [GitHub link](https://github.com/Saujanya0910/On-Screen-Keyboard/blob/main/on-screen-keyboard.py)
Here is my entire code as of now

Comment: Please put your code in your question.

Comment: Code doesn't have anything that shows what have you tried yet to implement the `shift` button click.

Comment: I recommend to not give such a complicated code for us to understand what is being done, make another example similar to your situation and include it, so we can help on to it. Basically you will want to bind to window and whenever `'Shift'` is pressed you want to change the text of the button using `config()` but not sure how your defining your buttons there.

Comment: I've tried thing like simply replacing Button text using for-loop locally in a function but it won't work. Also tried replacing list items but these simple approaches don't work. I'll try the ` config() ` thing.

Comment: Start by writing a function that does the conversion. Connect the function to a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code in the Github link, suggest to:

- define a variable `shift_on` to hold the current state of `Shift` key
- define a list `letter_buttons` to hold the references of the letter buttons ('a' to 'z')

```
shift_on = False
letter_buttons = []
```

Then modify `buttonClick()` as below:

```py
def is_letter(s):
    return len(s) == 1 and 'a' <= s <= 'z'

def buttonClick(input):
    global shift_on
    if input == 'Shift':
        # toggle shift state
        shift_on = not shift_on
        # update the text of the letter buttons
        for btn in letter_buttons:
            text = btn['text']
            btn['text'] = text.upper() if shift_on else text.lower()
    else:
        if input == ' Space ':
            textBox.insert(INSERT,' ')
        elif input == 'Tab':
            textBox.insert(INSERT, '    ')
        elif input == '←':
            backspace()
        else:
            if is_letter(input):
                input = input.upper() if shift_on else input.lower()
            textBox.insert(INSERT, input)
```

And modify the for loop to create the buttons as below:

```py
for button in buttons:
    # command to run on every button click - buttonClick() function 
    cmd = lambda x = button: buttonClick(x)

    # for every button except 'space'
    if button != ' Space ':
        btn = tk.Button(keyboardApp,
            text = button, 
            width = 7,
            bg = 'black',
            fg = 'white',
            activebackground = 'white',
            activeforeground = 'black',
            relief = 'raised',
            padx = 3,
            pady = 3, 
            bd = 5,
            font=('arial', 12, 'bold'),
            command = cmd)
        btn.grid(row = varRow, column = varCol)
        # save the reference of letter buttons
        if is_letter(button):
            letter_buttons.append(btn)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @acw1668. This is exactly what I wanted my code to do!! Highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You should first make a function that does the conversion. For example from your code define a function that does something like

```
def shift_buttons():
    buttons = shift_buttons
```

**Note:** By buttons and shift_buttons I mean change the normal buttons from the keyboard to capital buttons in the on screen keyboard. Hope you understand what I mean.